# Windows recovery partition still accessible after deleting it

Tags: windows, command-line, partitioning

I want to remove the **Command Prompt** from the *Advanced settings* of Windows recovery. (I'm using Windows 11)

I have previously accomplished this on my Desktop PC, but I'm currently encountering an issue with my laptop.

I deleted the Windows partition using Diskpart. After selecting the Recovery partition, I deleted it using the command ***delete partition override***.

The following is the current output from Diskpart when using the ***list partition*** command:

```
Partizione ###   Tipo              Dim.     Offset
  ---------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partizione 1    Sistema            100 Mb  1024 Kb
  Partizione 2    Riservato           16 Mb   101 Mb
  Partizione 3    Primario           931 Gb   117 Mb
```

As you can see, the Recovery partition is no longer present (the list is identical to my Desktop PC,  where I was able to successfully remove the Command Prompt).

However, the problem is that if I reboot and access the *Advanced settings* of Windows recovery, I can still open and use the Command Prompt (the one located in the **X:** drive).

Honestly, I don't remember if I had performed any additional steps on my desktop PC to permanently remove the Command Prompt option from Windows recovery. Nevertheless, it does seem strange that it remains accessible after removing the recovery partition.

Do you have any suggestions on how can I fix this?

Thank you.

**EDIT**: To make it more clear, this is the view of *Advanced settings* on my Desktop PC which I want to replicate on my laptop. [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6my9V.jpg)

This is the current view of *Advanced settings* on my laptop. [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkAbH.jpg)

Comment: Could you endeavour to post text as text, rather than pictures. Pictures of text cannot be indexed by google or read by software for the sight-impaired. Copy/paste, select then Ctrl/K to format as 'code'

Comment: Thank you. I modified the question.